# rewriting the inverse image

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

If   $\phi_k:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions, for all $k\geq0$ and $$\phi=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }\phi_n$$

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, is possible to write $\phi^{-1}(A)$ through $\phi_1^{-1}(A),\phi_2^{-1}(A),\phi_3^{-1}(A),...$ ?

perhaps as an upper limit, lower of $\{ \phi_n^{-1}(A)\}$ ?